# Php $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] gives different ip everytime

Tags: php, ip

I am using Php superglobal `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` to get the client ip . But it always gives me different ip address and also ip provided by `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` is not correct my ip on local machine starts with 192.168. ... and so on but it gives me ip like 165.123. ... and when i open the page with different browsers it produces different results .

Comment: may be it is an external ipaddress which it is storing

Comment: What do you mean by external ip address

Comment: The IP you are seeing, is the IP of the firewall of your company.

Comment: @Shanukk i am not using any proxy but still i get wrong ip and differebt ip everytime .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The IP on your local machine is a private IP assigned by your router. A remote server gets the public IP of the WAN interface of the router. If the IP is changing, your ISP must be assigning your IP dynamically each time you connect.

Another possibility is that your ISP relays your web traffic through proxy servers. Then `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` is the IP of the proxy. If the IP changes each time, they have multiple proxies that they load balance.

Comment: isn't there any way to get the same ip consistently ? i looked at api of ipify.org and when i use their api it give a consistent ip

Comment: It depends on the ISP whether they give you a consistent IP every time. I'm not sure what ipify.org is doing differently, maybe there's some caching.

Comment: i am trying to fix session hijacking by storing IP address of a user. But each time i run this $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] it gives me different IP so thus my fix always fails. So how to manage getting a correct address of remote machine that is calling the URL?

Comment: @MadhavaraoKulkarni You can't do it using IP address, and shouldn't try.